# HoughCircles votes output in python

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, output, hough-transform

I'm detecting circles using HoughCircles in python and was wondering if anyone know how the get the confidence level (im my understanding the votes vector) when using HoughCircles.

I ran the following code, and the output was (x,y,radius). When trying HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT instead of HOUGH_GRADIENT output remained (x,y,radius).
Thank you.

```
        a = cv.HoughCircles(imgray, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, i, 20,
                    param1=50, param2=30,
                    minRadius=0, maxRadius=40)
```